# PHP calendar showing dates on the right day of the week

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have created a table in my MySQL DB which contains the dates for a whole month.

I am then trying to display them in a table (looking like a calendar)

I have created a script, so the first day of the month shows on the right day (eg Saturday for October).

I'm then displaying all other dates after it.

**Code**

```
$Firstdate = date('Y-m-01');
       $FirstDay = date("N", strtotime($Firstdate));



if ($FirstDay == 1) {}
if ($FirstDay == 2) { echo"<td></td>";}
if ($FirstDay == 3) { echo"<td></td> <td></td>";}
if ($FirstDay == 4) { echo"<td></td> <td></td> <td></td>";}
if ($FirstDay == 5) { echo"<td></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td>";}
if ($FirstDay == 6) { echo"<td></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td>";}
if ($FirstDay == 7) { echo"<td></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td>";}

 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendar")or die('ERROR 315' );
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
  for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result); $i++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $TheDate = $row ['date'];
   $TheDateF = date("jS", strtotime($TheDate));

echo " <td> &nbsp;&nbsp;$TheDateF</Center><br><br><br><br></td>";   

   if ($i % 7 == 0) {
              echo '</tr><tr>'; // it's time no move to next row
            }
  }
```

This starts on the correct day, however see screenshot below, I need it to start a new row after the Sunday date:

[image]

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: Is there any reason that you are hard-coding the calendar because there are plenty of plugin available.

Comment: It's at my clients request...

Comment: @Suraj - Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I would just use a plugin like FullCalendar (http://fullcalendar.io). There are several others. It will save you a lot of time and problems, and save your client a lot of money. Then you can get on with providing them some real value and not re-inventing a (relatively complex) wheel

Comment: @ADyson Thanks but im so close to having a bespoke one without a plugin, just this issue here.

Comment: Also, the calendar will be populated with items from my DB

Comment: @user3092953 fullCalendar fully supports populating the calendar with items from your DB, using a variety of possible methods, and does all sorts of other good stuff which it would take someone else ages to build. If you're close to finishing this project then by all means fix it, but it sort of seems to me like you will soon want other features that will be harder to do. Users always add to the requirements as soon as they have got version 1 (or often, before).

Comment: @ADyson, I appreciate that, however It's just going to be a basic table showing data from the DB, noting will be added from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Modify according to your need. I'm pretty sure this will help you.

```
<?php
/* Set the default timezone */
date_default_timezone_set("America/Montreal");

/* Set the date */
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));

$day = date('d', $date);
$month = date('m', $date);
$year = date('Y', $date);
$firstDay = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year);
$title = strftime('%B', $firstDay);
$dayOfWeek = date('D', $firstDay);
$daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);
/* Get the name of the week days */
$timestamp = strtotime('next Sunday');
$weekDays = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
  $weekDays[] = strftime('%a', $timestamp);
  $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
}
$blank = date('w', strtotime("{$year}-{$month}-01"));
?>
<table class='table table-bordered' border=1 style="table-layout: fixed;">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="7" class="text-center"> <?php echo $title ?> <?php echo $year ?> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <?php foreach($weekDays as $key => $weekDay) : ?>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $weekDay ?></td>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < $blank; $i++): ?>
      <td></td>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $daysInMonth; $i++): ?>
      <?php if($day == $i): ?>
        <td><strong><?php echo $i ?></strong></td>
      <?php else: ?>
        <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if(($i + $blank) % 7 == 0): ?>
        </tr><tr>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php for($i = 0; ($i + $blank + $daysInMonth) % 7 != 0; $i++): ?>
      <td></td>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Source
http://code.runnable.com/VKxpI5dzCMkTrRq1/simple-calendar-for-php

Comment: Great! Thanks. How can I add items to a day? (Where in the code do I add this?)